# inverse survival function and PPF(ICDF) of normal distribution?

Tags: c++, statistics

Is there an inbuilt c/c++ function for inverse survival function  and quantile function (percent-point function or inverse cumulative distribution function) of normal distribution like the one in `scipy.stats.norm.isf`?

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.  And none in the Standard Library - you'd need to write one yourself, or find a suitable library.